# compiling gtk+3 project with msys on windows

Tags: windows, gtk3, msys2

I'm trying to compile a C project on windows that has a dependency on gtk+-3.0 (using msys to build it). Here's the list of gtk packages that I installed:

```
$ pacman -Ss gtk | grep installed
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-glib2 2.52.3-1 [installed]
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gtk3 3.22.18-1 [installed]
mingw32/mingw-w64-i686-gtkmm3 3.22.0-1 [installed]
mingw64/mingw-w64-x86_64-glib2 2.52.3-1 [installed]
msys/glib2 2.48.2-1 [installed]
```

However, when I run `./configure` I get the following error:

```
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (gtk+-3.0 >= gtk_required_version) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-3.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GTK_CFLAGS and GTK_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config. See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to compiling directly from `bash` instead of the shell environment setup for building native 32-bit apps (`msys2_shell.cmd -mingw32`)